# Google sheet query using dynamic importranges

Tags: google-sheets

Hope someone can help me with this one:

I have multiple sheets and I want to dynamically merge all data into 1 sheet.

In my mastersheet I made a tab with all the URLS and ranges that I want to import.
In a cell I merge all the importranges to use them in my query.
But my query is not accepting the reference to the cell with all my merged importranges., allthough they are correctly merged.

My goal is to automatically expand my query range when a sheet-url and range is added to the list of all sheets.

Comment: Can you share a sheet with some sample data and how is your formula working so far? It will be easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: In my mastersheet I have:
URL, TAB, RANGE, and a cell that merges this data.

In cell A1 I have:
=JOIN(";";QUERY(URL!A3:F;"SELECT F WHERE F <>''"))
So this merges everything in the right way to become this type of query:
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("URL","TAB!RANGE");IMPORTRANGE("URL2","TAB2!RANGE2")},"select * where Col1<>''")

As soon as I combine this in my own query I get an error:
=QUERY({URL!A1};"SELECT *")

Comment: Please add all relevant information directly in the question instead of posting it as comments. Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use the text output of a cell as an input to a formula.  It is not allowed in Google Sheets.